# how to find all result with any keyword matched in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called users. that table has more than 10 columns. i want to make a search program that return all row if any keyword match in a string.

check my attachment.. in that attachment when i am trying to search "rina" as like 
`select * from users where first_name like "%riaa%" or last_name like '%rina%'`

in this condition i am getting result as i was expected. **but when i try to search '%rina sharma%'**  i am getting no result found. my query is searching whole keyword in each cell.

like
is 1st name have "rina sharma" => false
is 2nd name have "rina sharma" => false

i want that either "rina"or "sharma" if any keyword matched that result should be appear.

[image]

Comment: you will need to split your keyword and do dynamic where clause. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264201/mysql-search-string-with-spaces-using-like](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264201/mysql-search-string-with-spaces-using-like). check this answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM id c
WHERE c.name REGEXP 'rina|sharma';
```

Comment: this code is working fine but we have to re-structure  search keyword. that will add one more layer of coding..

is any another option so that code line will be less?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question as to what is required to be re-structured?

Comment: my requirement is either user will search like this
rina,jhon,rita,sales manager
or
rina sales manager APAC
basically by comma separated or space separated  
so it will be log search keyword.. 
now we need to parse the keyWord as keyword1 | keyWord2
than i have to query

Comment: overall your code is satisfying my requirement. so 
thanks. i am accepting this answer

Answer (score 0):

Use `BOOLEAN MODE`

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE MATCH (first_name,last_name) 
     AGAINST ('+rina +sharma' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Comment: i am getting this error
 Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE 
     CONCAT_WS(`first_name` , ' ', `last_name` ) LIKE '%rina sharma%'
```

For more details on ws_concat() refer http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-concat_ws-function.php

Comment: @harshit
your code is returning following result

 MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0004 sec)

it should be 3 result but getting none?

Comment: Try simple concat() instead `SELECT * FROM users WHERE 
     CONCAT(first_name , ' ', last_name ) LIKE '%rina sharma%' `

Comment: when i use just contact with '%rina sharma%' i get the result but
when i try with ' %sudhir kumar gupta%' and '%sudhir gupta admin%'  it was no result found. But there was one result

Comment: Could you please tell in which field kumar and admin are being saved are they in first name and last name field.

Comment: yes arpita
i have first_name | middle_name | Last_name | role
 <br />
Here kumar is last_name (lot of kumar will be available with this surname) and admin is role

Comment: If you want to search along with role also you should update your query to `SELECT * FROM users WHERE CONCAT(first_name , ' ', last_name, ' ', role ) LIKE '%sudhir gupta admin%'  `

Comment: And for Kumar are you sure it is in `last_name` not in `middle_name`

Comment: "kumar" is in last_name but it can be in any cell. i want to look into few columns only.

first_name middle_name last_name
  
sudhir kumar gupta
kumar sudhir gupta
gupta sudhir kumar
gupta kumar sudhir


this can be vary

Comment: Sudhir, the question you are asking now varies a bit with the original question so update the question, Mean while I will share the updated query also.